# How to fetch array value from new:CActiveRecord:private

Tags: php, yii

i have the following array
Ticket Object ( [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [TicketId] => 00002 [TicketTitle] => testone [TicketOwner] => 70 [ClientCompanyName] => Hidden Oasis [ClientFirstName] => Brenda & David [ClientLastName] => Kilby [ClientAdminEmail] => manager@hiddenoasisrv.com [ClientPhone] => (928)765-2341 [SupportLevel] => bronze [SupportIssue] => Application error [HoursPurchased] => 2 [HoursBalanceAvailable] => 2 [TicketReviewedBy] => rezsys [TicketStatus] => Open [TicketStartDate] => 2009-08-29 21:25:00 [TicketClosedDate] => 2009-08-29 21:25:00 [TicketLastModified] => 2009-08-29 21:25:00 [TimeOfPhoneSupport] => AM ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 00002 [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )

How to fetch "TicketTitle" from the above array?

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();        
$open = Ticket::model()->findByAttributes(array('TicketStatus'=>$status));
print_r($open);
```

Comment: mate, its not a array, it is object. can you please add the code here?

Comment: $Criteria = new CDbCriteria();        
        $open = Ticket::model()->findByAttributes(array('TicketStatus'=>$status));
  print_r($open);

Comment: did u tried to access ticket id like `$open->TicketId`?